# java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe (Write failed)

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, tomcat, jpa

I have page in production, and sometimes I will get this error when visiting the home page:

```
java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe (Write failed)
java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:111)
java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:155)
java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:140)
com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.send(MysqlIO.java:3626)
com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2452)
com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2617)
com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2546)
com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.setAutoCommit(ConnectionImpl.java:4873)
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections.poll(PooledConnections.java:84)
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:186)
org.hibernate.internal.NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.java:35) 
...
```

which leads to this:

```
org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection
```

Also in my development environment, I get this warning when ever I restart my tomcat:

```
WARNING: The web application [myApplication] appears to have started a thread named [pool-5-thread-1] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:215)
...
```

this is my persistance.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1"
xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
<persistence-unit name="myApplication">
    <properties>
           <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/myApplication?autoReconnect=true&amp;useSSL=false"/> 
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="user" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="password" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action"
            value="create" />
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

I made sure the I was closing the EntityManager where ever I opened one:

I also tried adding a connection pool:

```
    <!-- Configuring Connection Pool -->
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size" value="5" />
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size" value="20" />
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout" value="500" />
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements" value="50" />
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period" value="2000" />
```

but I am still having these two issues!

I read that  the Broken pipe exception is caused by the client trying to use a closed connection, but in the involved query, I'm getting a new entity manager.

```
@RequestMapping("/")
public String showHomePage(Model model, HttpSession session) {
    if (session.getAttribute("cart") == null) {
        session.setAttribute("cart", new ShoppingCart());
    }
    List<Category> categories = categoryService.findAllCategories();
    model.addAttribute("categories", categories);
    List<Product> products = productService.findAllSellableProducts();
    for (Product product : products) {
        product.setInventories(inventoryService.findInvenoriesByProduct(product));
    }
    model.addAttribute("products", products);
    return "index2";
}

public List<Category> findAllCategories() {
    EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
    try {
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        List<Category> categories = categoryDAO.findAllCategories(em);
        em.getTransaction().commit();
        return categories;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw e;
    } finally {
        em.close();
    }
}
```

Hopefully someone can see what I'm doing wrong here.

thanks

Comment: I wanted to add that once I hit reload a few times, The page is finally loaded